Series Expansion of logarithm of integral by Landau and Lifshitz in Statistical Physics (First Part)
Let $$E(p,q) = E_0(p,q) + V(p,q)$$ where $V$ represents the small terms. To calculate the free energy of the body we put
$$
e^\frac{-F}{T} = \int' e^{-\frac{E_0(p,q) + V(p,q)}{T}} d\Gamma \approx \int' e^{-\frac{E_0(p,q)}{T}} \left(1 - \frac{V}{T} + \frac{V^2}{2T^2}\right) d\Gamma.
$$ And then "taking logarithms and again expanding in series we have to the same accuracy" the following formula:
$$
F = F_0 + \int' \left(V - \frac{V^2}{2T}\right)e^{\frac{F_0 - E_0}{T}}d\Gamma + \frac{1}{2T}\left[\int' Ve^{\frac{F_0 - E_0}{T}}d\Gamma \right]^2.
$$
I'm having trouble deriving the last formula from the previous. Seems like I would need to expand the logarithm of an integral but I have no idea on how to handle it.
I know that $$F = -T \ln \int e^{-\frac{E(p,q)}{T}} d \Gamma$$ holds and I feel like I have to use it. Also note that $$d\Gamma = \frac{dqdp}{(2\pi \hbar)^s}.$$

In a particular use case, you have to specify $E$ and $V$ and then you can calculate a truncated expansion of the free energy. Do you have a specific use case in mind? If not, I am afraid the formula that you show is as specific as you can get.

I'm having trouble deriving the last formula which should be a consequence of 32.2

Landau and Lifshitz used the usual formal expansion in a small parameter. If you do not know how to expand the logarithm of an integral, then let's introduce convenient notations and expand the logarithm of a series. Namely, we will use
$$
Z_0 = e^{-F_0/T} = \int' e^{-E_0/T} d\Gamma,
$$
$$
\langle V\rangle_0 = \frac1{Z_0}\int' V e^{-E_0/T} d\Gamma = \int' V e^{(F_0-E_0)/T} d\Gamma,
$$
$$
\quad
\langle V^2\rangle_0 = \frac1{Z_0}\int' V^2 e^{-E_0/T} d\Gamma = \int' V^2 e^{(F_0-E_0)/T} d\Gamma,
$$
where $E_0\equiv E_0(p,q)$.
Now formula 32.2 can be written as
$$
e^{-F/T} = e^{-F_0/T}\left(1 - \frac{\langle V\rangle_0}T + \frac{\langle V^2\rangle_0}{2T^2}+\ldots \right)
$$
Using the logarithm expansion $\log(1+x) = x - x^2/2+\ldots$ and preserving terms up to and including the second order in $V$, we obtain
$$
F = F_0 -T\log\left(1 - \frac{\langle V\rangle_0}T + \frac{\langle V^2\rangle_0}{2T^2}+\ldots \right) = F_0 + \langle V\rangle_0 - \frac1{2T}\left(\langle V^2\rangle_0 - \langle V\rangle_0^2 \right) + \ldots
$$
Now the required formula is obtained after substituting the averages $\langle V\rangle_0$, $\langle V^2\rangle_0$ in the form of integrals.

It's just a use of the Newton-Mercator series, the fact that there are integrals plays no role. When $x \ll 1$ you have:
$$\ln 1+x \simeq 1 + x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 $$
The important thing you should note is that the second and third integrals in 32.2 are small compared to the first one (the whole section relies on the fact that $V$ is a small perturbation to the system without $V$). Starting from your equation for $F$, name the big integral $Z_0$ and use common factor, then you can expand in terms of the small parameter $x$ (the quotient between the second plus the third integral and $Z_0$).
$$ F = -T\ln Z_0 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{Z_0}(\text{the other integrals})
                 \right)
   = -T\ln Z_0 - T\ln (1+x)
$$
$$ F \simeq -F_0 - T \left(x - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) $$
